# Bokeh で　ガントチャートを作ることはできるでしょうか？

Tags: python, bokeh

python初級者です。
python 、plotlyでガントチャートを作成し、しばしば利用しています。
しかし、tooltipが柔軟でなく、工夫の余地がなさそうです。

Bokehはtooltipが柔軟で、表示させる内容は自由にカスタマイズできます。

しかし、ガントチャートを作れるのかが分かりません。

ご指導よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 「初心者です」は質問の説明にはなりませんので、どうしても書きたい場合にはプロフィールの自己紹介欄に設定しましょう。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

出来ると言えば出来るでしょう。以下の記事の2つ目の回答が、Bokehでガントチャートを表示する内容になっています。
ただし、表示内容はシンプルですね。
色々と付加情報表示にこだわるなら、それは別途ということでしょうか。
[How to plot stacked event duration (Gantt Charts) using Python Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31820578/9014308)

この回答の後で仕様変更になって、`bokeh.charts`はサポートされなくなったようですが、コメントアウトすれば動作しました。
回答プログラムの2行コメントアウト・2行数値調整で、ほぼ同様の結果が出来ています。

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_notebook, output_file
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Range1d
from bokeh.models.tools import HoverTool
from datetime import datetime
#from bokeh.charts import Bar  # コメントアウト
#output_notebook()             # コメントアウト
#output_file('GanntChart.html') #use this to create a standalone html file to send to others
import pandas as ps

DF=ps.DataFrame(columns=['Item','Start','End','Color'])
Items=[
    ['Contract Review & Award','2015-7-22','2015-8-7','red'],
    ['Submit SOW','2015-8-10','2015-8-14','gray'],
    ['Initial Field Study','2015-8-17','2015-8-21','gray'],
    ['Topographic Procesing','2015-9-1','2016-6-1','gray'],
    ['Init. Hydrodynamic Modeling','2016-1-2','2016-3-15','gray'],
    ['Prepare Suitability Curves','2016-2-1','2016-3-1','gray'],
    ['Improvement Conceptual Designs','2016-5-1','2016-6-1','gray'],
    ['Retrieve Water Level Data','2016-8-15','2016-9-15','gray'],
    ['Finalize Hydrodynamic Models','2016-9-15','2016-10-15','gray'],
    ['Determine Passability','2016-9-15','2016-10-1','gray'],
    ['Finalize Improvement Concepts','2016-10-1','2016-10-31','gray'],
    ['Stakeholder Meeting','2016-10-20','2016-10-21','blue'],
    ['Completion of Project','2016-11-1','2016-11-30','red']
    ] #first items on bottom

for i,Dat in enumerate(Items[::-1]):
    DF.loc[i]=Dat

#convert strings to datetime fields:
DF['Start_dt']=ps.to_datetime(DF.Start)
DF['End_dt']=ps.to_datetime(DF.End)

G=figure(title='Project Schedule',x_axis_type='datetime',width=800,height=400,y_range=DF.Item.tolist(),
        x_range=Range1d(DF.Start_dt.min(),DF.End_dt.max()), tools='save')

hover=HoverTool(tooltips="Task: @Item<br>\
Start: @Start<br>\
End: @End")
G.add_tools(hover)

DF['ID']=DF.index+0.3   # 数値調整 元は 0.8
DF['ID1']=DF.index+0.7  # 数値調整 元は 1.2
CDS=ColumnDataSource(DF)
G.quad(left='Start_dt', right='End_dt', bottom='ID', top='ID1',source=CDS,color="Color")
#G.rect(,"Item",source=CDS)
show(G)
```

[image: Bokehガントチャート]

---

Bokehライブラリ説明サイトの GALLERY に、類似の形でオリンピック100mメダリスト記録の変遷が図になっています。
これもシンプルですね。
[bar_intervals.py](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/bar_intervals.html)

---

Python gantt chartで簡単に検索した中では、色々な情報をスケジュールの線と同時に表示するなら、Bokehよりも以下の2つが良さそうです。

- [Python-Gantt](https://xael.org/pages/python-gantt-en.html)
- [stefanSchinkel/gantt](https://github.com/stefanSchinkel/gantt)

まあ、お使いの plotly とか、他に matplotlib なんかも以下のような例があります。

- [Pythonライブラリ「plotly」でガントチャートを表示する](https://maruzhang.hatenablog.com/entry/2019/05/01/143718)
- [Quick Gantt Chart with Matplotlib](https://sukhbinder.wordpress.com/2016/05/10/quick-gantt-chart-with-matplotlib/)

Comment: ありがとうございます。とても勉強になりました。これを足掛かりにBokehで検討してみます。ガントチャートにpan,zoom機能がどうしても欲しいです。